# How to use radio button in AngularJS 2?

Tags: angularjs

I am sorry to say that I failed to find a radio button example in the AngularJS 2 FORMS documentation. Please give a live example. Thanks.

Comment: Angular2 is still very betaish, if you're working on something for production you probably want to be working in 1.x for the time being (who knows though maybe your business lives on the edge :) )

Answer (score 1):

Please try those code:

Html

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" [checked]="radioValue" (click)="clickRadio()"/>
</form>
radio value: {{radioValue}}
```

ts

```
radioValue:boolean = false;
clickRadio(){
  this.radioValue = !this.radioValue
}
```